# Formatting of components in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I have just started programming in Swing. I am making a Fitness application using Swing. I have 2 questions:

1. Whenever I click 'Calculate Scales' it should display the results only once, but it is displaying as many times as I click.  How can I solve this?
2. How can I set limit of `JTextField` up to 3 digits in my code?

Here is my code. Correct me if I am going wrong somewhere. Suggest me where I can make improvements.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;//since obsolete
class H1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4,l5;
 JTextField t1,t2,t3;
 JRadioButton r1,r2;
ButtonGroup bg1;
JLabel bmr;
  JLabel bmi;
int click=0;
JButton b1,b2;Container c1;
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

  H1 j1 =new H1();
  j1.setTitle("Personal  Scales ");
  j1.setSize(1000,1000);
  j1.setVisible(true);
  j1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  j1.pack();
 }

H1()
{

c1=this.getContentPane();
setLayout(new BoxLayout(c1,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


JPanel j1 = new JPanel();
j1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
t1 = new JTextField(10);
l1=new JLabel("Height");
j1.add(l1);
j1.add(t1);
c1.add(j1);


JPanel j2 = new JPanel();
j2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
l2=new JLabel("Weight");
t2 = new JTextField(10);
j2.add(l2);
j2.add(t2);
c1.add(j2);



JPanel j3 = new JPanel();
j3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
l3=new JLabel("Age");
t3 = new JTextField(10);
j3.add(l3);
j3.add(t3);
c1.add(j3);


JPanel j4 = new JPanel();
j4.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
l4=new JLabel("Sex");
bg1=new ButtonGroup();
r1=new JRadioButton("M");
r2=new JRadioButton("F");
bg1.add(r1);//button grouping is done to avoid multiple selection of radio button
bg1.add(r2);
j4.add(l4);
j4.add(r1);
j4.add(r2);
c1.add(j4);


JPanel j5 = new JPanel();
j5.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

b1=new JButton("Calculate Scales");//creating instance of JButton  
j5.add(b1);
c1.add(j5);
b1.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 { 

  click +=1;
  //JLabel bmr;
  //JLabel bmi;
  long ht=Long.parseLong(t1.getText());
  long wt=Long.parseLong(t2.getText());
  long age=Long.parseLong(t3.getText());
  //JPanel j6 = new JPanel();

  //j6.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


  double bmi1 = wt/Math.pow((ht * 0.01),2);

  String bmi2 = Double.toString(bmi1);//since double  cant be added to container 

  bmi=new JLabel("BMI     "+bmi2); 

  //c1.add(j6);
 // JPanel j7 = new JPanel();
  //j7.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  double bmr1;String bmr2;

if(r1.isSelected())
  bmr1 = 66.47 +(13.75 * wt) + (5.003 * ht) - (6.775 * age);

else

  bmr1 = 655.1 +(9.563 * wt) + (1.85 * ht) - (4.676 * age);


 bmr2=Double.toString(bmr1);
 bmr=new JLabel("BMR     "+bmr2);

if(click>1)
  {
   c1.remove(bmi);
   c1.remove(bmr);
  }

/*j6.add(bmi);
j6.add(bmr);*/

  c1.add(bmi);
  c1.add(bmr);

}
}
```

Comment: 1) This is not a 'Doubt & Assurance' site, but a 'Question and Answer' site - so ask questions if you will, but save your doubts for used car salesmen and politicians. 2) Each thread should have one question with (ideally) one answer, so decide which question you'd like answered on this thread and move the other to a new question. 3) That code was marked up as though it were a runnable JavaScript snippet.  That only works for JavaScript.  Use instead the `{}` button to denote a code snippet in any other language. ..

Comment: .. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 5) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 6) *"How can I set limit of `JTextField` up to 3 digits..?"*  Consider using a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Throwing the dictionary at someone does nothing to detract from nhgrif's point and does more to undermine your own. I would expect better from a member of the community with over 100k reputation. nhgrif was simply pointing out the way our section of the site works. There is no need to be rude about it just because you have been shown to be wrong or get antsy over a semantic word like "might".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also newer to java, so correct me if I'm wrong and cause of that, I can't write you a comment and have to write an answer ;)

As I can see it, you make a new JLabel each time you click the Button.
Try to use eg. `bmi.setText("BMI here" + bmi2);` for your result description through `setText()` you only change the Text in this label. And also as variable declaration use `JLabel bmi = null;`

Maybe you also can add a JPanel to display your result to get the JLabel a fixed position and initializing it.

I hope that I can help you ;)
Zorian